# How to add custom icon to Kubuntu 11.10 launcher?

Tags: 11.10, launcher, kubuntu

I have a shell script, idea, that simply sets JAVA_HOME then launches idea.sh.  It doesn't show in a Dash Home search so I can't use the drag-and-drop way of adding it to the launcher.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Wondering ?**

Do you have the Kubuntu ?  This is tagged with the Kubuntu tag and the question is:"How to add custom icon to Kubuntu 11.10 launcher?". The Kubuntu /1/ is: "An official derivative of Ubuntu Linux that uses the KDE graphical environment /2/".

**If you have a Kubuntu desktop**

**With the GUI**

The KDE is having the Menu editor /3/. K > Applications > Help > Application Manuals > Settings > Menu Editor

**Manual/DIY**

The KDE is using the freedesktop specifications /4/, /5/.

a) Make a desktop file

b) Drop it to the ~/.local/share/applications/ or /usr/share/applications/

**Links**

1. http://www.kubuntu.org/
2. http://www.kde.org/
3. http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html
4. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/
5. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications

Comment: I copied google-chrome.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications, made some changes, and added a line in ~/.local/share/applications.defaults.list and the icon still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the launcher icon (the KDE gears icon bottom left) and click on `Edit Applications...`, this will open a menu editor that will allow you to add a entry anywhere in the launcher.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to work.  Any idea why?

Comment: are you using the standard application launcher?

Comment: Yes, I think I'm using the standard application launcher.

Comment: After I click 'Edit Applications', then 'New Item' I add the item as usual (shell script, also idea.sh).   Then I click 'Save'.  Everything looks okay, except I don't see the new item anywhere in the menus and it's gone when I open up the KDE Menu Editor again.

Answer (score 0):

user26687 led me most of the way there.  I used gnome-desktop-item-edit as described at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfTfc-DLtpU to create a .desktop file.  Then I used Dash home to search for the app and dragged-and-dropped the icon into the launcher.